# Identify text in the format "firstname.middlename.lastname" or "firstname,middlename,lastname"

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I want to remove text in the format of "firstname.middlename.lastname" or "firstname,middlename,lastname".

Sometimes there won't be any middle name then it would be only firstname.

```
Function isEmail(ByVal data As String)

Dim mailReg As Object
Set mailReg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

Dim regpattern As String
regpattern = "/[a-z]+./[a-z]"

Dim arr1() As String
Dim element As Variant
Dim strInput As String

arr1() = Split(data, " ")

For Each element In arr1
    strInput = element
    mailReg.IgnoreCase = True
    mailReg.Global = True
    mailReg.Pattern = regpattern
    If mailReg.Test(strInput) = True Then
        isEmail = (strInput)
    End If
Next element

End Function
```

Comment: Do you have more information on what you are trying to do here? What are your sample inputs? What are valid inputs? What is your expected result? And what do you mean with "sometimes it's only first name"? Just a single word?

Comment: so my text is in the following format . 1) ticket booking for firstname.middlename.lastname. 2) firstname,middlename,lastname food expenses 3) foreign trip firstname.lastname easytrrp. i want to extract the firstname middlename and last name in each of the cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not use Regex:

```
Option Explicit
Function isEmail(ByVal data As String) As Boolean
    Dim u As Long, temp As String, brr
    isEmail = False
    temp = Replace(data, ".", ",")

    If InStr(temp, ",") = 0 Then Exit Function

    brr = Split(temp, ",")
    u = UBound(brr)
    If u = 1 Or u = 2 Then
        isEmail = True
        Exit Function
    End If

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your code, with this i am able to identify the type of data but how do i extract the firstname.middlename.lastname using the above code.

Answer (score 0):

seems you could use this

```
Function isEmail(ByVal data As String) As Boolean
    Dim l As Long
    l = Len(data) - Len(Replace(Replace(data, ",", "."), ".", vbNullString))
    isEmail = l >= 1 And l <= 2
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but using the above code, i am unable to extract the firstname.middlename.last name from my string.

Comment: and where did you ask for that in your question?

Comment: Apologies this was the first time i was drafting question on stack over flow, so had missed including that. if you can provide me the code for that, it would be really useful.

Comment: as per this site rules you should: 1) accept a working solution (if any) for your_original_ question 2) start a new topic for the new issue

Comment: Fine. Would you mind explaining why you chose a longer code as the solution?

Comment: both answers are correct, i want to accept both of them, but since it is not allowing to accept both, i choose the one which came first.

Comment: and which one are you using?